# Count interactions with unique accounts in financial transaction dataset

Tags: r

I have a question about a dataset with financial transactions:

```
  Account_from  Account_to  Value 
1       1           2        25.0
2       1           3        30.0
3       2           1        28.0
4       2           3        10.0
5       2           3        12.0
6       3           1        40.0
7       3           1        30.0
8       3           1        20.0
```

Each row represents a transaction. I would like to create an extra column with a variable containing the information of the number of interactions with each unique account. 
That it would look like the following:

```
  Account_from  Account_to  Value  Count_interactions_out  Count_interactions_in 
1       1           2        25.0           2                       2
2       1           3        30.0           2                       2
3       2           1        28.0           2                       1
4       2           3        10.0           2                       1
5       2           3        12.0           2                       1
6       3           1        40.0           1                       2
7       3           1        30.0           1                       2
8       3           1        20.0           1                       2
```

`Account 3` only interacts with `account 1`, therefore `Count_interactions_out` is 1. However, it receives interactions from `account 1 and 2`, therefore the `count_interactions_in` is 2.

How can I apply this to the whole dataset?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with base R, where `ave()` is used

```
df <- cbind(df, 
            with(df, list(
              Count_interactions_out = ave(Account_to,Account_from,FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))), 
              Count_interactions_in = ave(Account_from,Account_to,FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)))[match(Account_from,Account_to,)])))
```

such that

```
> df
  Account_from Account_to Value Count_interactions_out Count_interactions_in
1            1          2    25                      2                     2
2            1          3    30                      2                     2
3            2          1    28                      2                     1
4            2          3    10                      2                     1
5            2          3    12                      2                     1
6            3          1    40                      1                     2
7            3          1    30                      1                     2
8            3          1    20                      1                     2
```

or

```
df <- within(df, list(
  Count_interactions_out <- ave(Account_to,Account_from,FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))), 
  Count_interactions_in <- ave(Account_from,Account_to,FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)))[match(Account_from,Account_to,)]))
```

such that

```
> df
  Account_from Account_to Value Count_interactions_in Count_interactions_out
1            1          2    25                     2                      2
2            1          3    30                     2                      2
3            2          1    28                     1                      2
4            2          3    10                     1                      2
5            2          3    12                     1                      2
6            3          1    40                     2                      1
7            3          1    30                     2                      1
8            3          1    20                     2                      1
```

Comment: @florisviss if you think my code does help and is the one you like, please feel free to accept it by taking check mark under votes

Comment: I will thanks, i have another question to add multiple columns in the same dataset, i posted the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59427648/add-multiple-variablescolumns-in-financial-dataset-with-time-amount-informatio. If you could help it would be really nice

Comment: @florisviss Okey, I will have a look at it

Comment: @florisviss I added my solution for your newly posted question, so you can check it out

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
financial.data %>%
   group_by(Account_from) %>%
   mutate(Count_interactions_out = nlevels(factor(Account_to))) %>%
   ungroup() %>%
   group_by(Account_to) %>%
   mutate(Count_interactions_in = nlevels(factor(Account_from))) %>%
   ungroup()
```