# Add multiple variables(columns) in financial dataset with time/amount information

Tags: r

I have another question about a dataset with financial transactions:

```
  Account_from  Account_to  Value  Timestamp
1       1           2        25.0      0
2       1           3        30.0      1
3       2           1        28.0      0
4       2           3        10.0      2
5       2           3        12.0      2
6       3           1        40.0      0
7       3           1        30.0      3
8       3           1        20.0      4
```

Each row represents a transaction. I would like to create extra columns with variables containing information about the following:

- average_amount_outgoing
- average_amount_incoming
- sum_amount_outgoing
- sum_amount_incoming
- max_amount_out
- max_amount_in
- min_amount_out
- min_amount_in
- min_interval_out (between to transactions, based on timestamp value)
- max_interval_out (between to transactions, based on timestamp value)
- min_interval_in (between to transactions, based on timestamp value)
- max_interval_in (between to transactions, based on timestamp value)

Based on Account_from, that it would look like the following: (in one dataset)

```
  Account_from  Account_to  Value    Timestamp  Avg_amt_out  Avg_amt_inc  Sum_amt_out  Sum_amt_inc  max_amt_out 
1       1           2        25.0        0         27.5         29.50         55.0        118.0        30.0      
2       1           3        30.0        1         27.5         29.50         55.0        118.0        30.0       
3       2           1        28.0        0         16.67        25.0          50.0         25.0        28.0      
4       2           3        10.0        2         16.67        25.0          50.0         25.0        28.0
5       2           3        12.0        2         16.67        25.0          50.0         25.0        28.0
6       3           1        40.0        0         30.0         17.33         90.0         52.0        40.0        
7       3           1        30.0        3         30.0         17.33         90.0         52.0        40.0
8       3           1        20.0        4         30.0         17.33         90.0         52.0        40.0
```

```
  max_amt_in   min_amt_out  min_amt_in  min_int_out max_int_out min_int_in max_int_in
1    40.0          25.0        20.0         1            1           1         3
2    40.0          25.0        20.0         1            1           1         3      
3    25.0          10.0        25.0         2            2           0         0
4    25.0          10.0        25.0         2            2           0         0
5    25.0          10.0        25.0         2            2           0         0
6    30.0          20.0        10.0         1            3           1         1
7    30.0          20.0        10.0         1            3           1         1
8    30.0          20.0        10.0         1            3           1         1
```

How can I apply this to the whole dataset?

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you to don't duplicate data, it's a best practice. Create another table based on your `Account_from`.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It's helpful to see what about your approach hasn't worked, and what research you've done. That also means we wouldn't have to guess what calculations you're trying to do based on the example headings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution in base R. You can try the code below

```
df <- cbind(df, with(df, list(
  Avg_amt_out = ave(Value,Account_from,FUN = mean), 
  Avg_amt_inc = ave(Value,Account_to,FUN = mean)[match(Account_from,Account_to,)],
  Sum_amt_out = ave(Value,Account_from,FUN = sum), 
  Sum_amt_inc = ave(Value,Account_to,FUN = sum)[match(Account_from,Account_to,)],
  max_amt_out = ave(Value,Account_from,FUN = max), 
  max_amt_inc = ave(Value,Account_to,FUN = max)[match(Account_from,Account_to,)],
  min_amt_out = ave(Value,Account_from,FUN = min), 
  min_amt_inc = ave(Value,Account_to,FUN = min)[match(Account_from,Account_to,)],
  min_int_out = ave(Timestamp,Account_from,FUN = function(x) ifelse(length(unique(x))==1,unique(x),min(diff(unique(x))))),
  max_int_out = ave(Timestamp,Account_from,FUN = function(x) ifelse(length(unique(x))==1,unique(x),max(diff(unique(x))))),
  min_int_in = ave(Timestamp,Account_to,FUN = function(x) ifelse(length(unique(x))==1,unique(x),min(diff(unique(x)))))[match(Account_from,Account_to,)],
  max_int_in = ave(Timestamp,Account_to,FUN = function(x) ifelse(length(unique(x))==1,unique(x),max(diff(unique(x)))))[match(Account_from,Account_to,)]
)
)
)
```

such that

```
> df
  Account_from Account_to Value Timestamp Avg_amt_out Avg_amt_inc Sum_amt_out Sum_amt_inc max_amt_out
1            1          2    25         0    27.50000    29.50000          55         118          30
2            1          3    30         1    27.50000    29.50000          55         118          30
3            2          1    28         0    16.66667    25.00000          50          25          28
4            2          3    10         2    16.66667    25.00000          50          25          28
5            2          3    12         2    16.66667    25.00000          50          25          28
6            3          1    40         0    30.00000    17.33333          90          52          40
7            3          1    30         3    30.00000    17.33333          90          52          40
8            3          1    20         4    30.00000    17.33333          90          52          40
  max_amt_inc min_amt_out min_amt_inc min_int_out max_int_out min_int_in max_int_in
1          40          25          20           1           1          1          3
2          40          25          20           1           1          1          3
3          25          10          25           2           2          0          0
4          25          10          25           2           2          0          0
5          25          10          25           2           2          0          0
6          30          20          10           1           3          1          1
7          30          20          10           1           3          1          1
8          30          20          10           1           3          1          1
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(Account_from = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L
), Account_to = c(2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Value = c(25, 
30, 28, 10, 12, 40, 30, 20), Timestamp = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 
0L, 3L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: If you have time, I am stuck at another feature engineering problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59561897/combining-two-financial-datasets-with-interactive-account-balance-variable-over?noredirect=1#comment105293836_59561897. Would help a lot thanks

Comment: could you maybe take a loot at the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60115847/add-new-variables-financial-dataset-r?noredirect=1#comment106327575_60115847 . thanks

Answer (score 4):

We can use `mutate_at` for each grouping separately

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(Account_from) %>% 
   mutate_at(vars(Value), 
     list(average_amount_out = ~mean(.), 
          sum_amount_out = ~ sum(.), 
          max_amount_out = ~ max(.),
          min_amount_out = ~ min(.))) %>%
  group_by(Account_to) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(Value), 
      list(average_amount_in = ~mean(.), 
           sum_amount_in = ~ sum(.), 
           max_amount_in = ~ max(.), 
           min_amount_in = ~ min(.)))
```