# Add new variables financial dataset r

Tags: r

I have a question about a financial transaction dataset.
The data set look as the following:

```
    Account_from  Account_to  Value  Timestamp  
1         1           2        10        1
2         1           3        15        1
3         3           4        20        1
4         2           1        10        2
5         1           3        25        2
6         2           1        15        3
7         1           3        10        3
8         1           4        20        4
```

I would like to create a couple of extra variables based on the `account from` column. The variables I want to create are : 
`(total value out of account from in the last two timestamps)`,

`(total value incoming of account from in the last two timestamps)`,

`(total transaction value out that timestamp of all transaction done during that timestamp)`,

`(value out of account from / previous value out of account from),`

That it will look like this:

```
    Acc_from  Acc_to  Value  Timestamp  Tot_val_out  Tot_val_inc  Tot_val_out_1time   val_out/prev_val_out
1       1        2     10        1           10           0              45                    0
2       1        3     15        1           25           0              45                   1.5
3       3        4     20        1           20           15             45                    0
4       2        1     10        2           10           10             35                    0
5       1        3     25        2           50           10             35                   1.67
6       2        1     15        3           25           0              25                   1.5
7       1        3     10        3           35           25             25                   0.4
8       1        4     20        4           30           15             20                    2
```

For example row 5 tot_val_out is 50, this means that account 1 transferred the amount of 50 in the last two timestamps (timestamps 1 and 2). At row 8 account 1 transferred 30 in the last two timestamps (timestamps 3 and 4).

The same should be done for incoming value.

Additionally I would like to create the variables:

`(number of transactions done by account from in the previous 4 timestamps)`

`(number of transactions done by account from in the previous 2 timestamps)`

So that:

```
    Account_from  Account_to  Value  Timestamp  Transactions_previous4  Transactions_previous2
1         1           2        10        1                 1                      1
2         1           3        15        1                 2                      2
3         3           4        20        1                 1                      1
4         2           1        10        2                 1                      1
5         1           3        25        2                 3                      3
6         2           1        15        3                 2                      2
7         1           3        10        3                 4                      2
8         1           4        20        4                 5                      2
```

At row 8 account 1 has made 5 transactions the last 4 timestamps (timestamps 1 till 4), but in the last 2 timestamps (timestamps 3 and 4) only 2 transactions.

I cannot figure out how to do this. It would be extremely helpfull if someone knows how to do this.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You could use `dplyr::mutate` and `zoo::rollapply`. So, something like `newdf <- df %>% mutate(Tot_val_out = rollaply( Acc_from , and here you add your wanted tranfromation)`

Comment: @novica thanks, but how do I apply that it only works for the last two timesteps?

Comment: can you explain a bit why `Tot_val_out` is 35 at row 7?

Comment: Yes of course, row 7 the ````Tot_val_out```` is 35 because account from (1) has made in the last two timesteps ( timestamp 2 and 3) two transactions. One at row 5 with the value of 25 and the second one at row 7 with the value of 10. Therefore in tot_val_out (of account from of that transaction (1)) is 35. Do you understand or should I explain further?

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding would you have any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R code

```
for (k in seq(nrow(df))) {
  nr <- seq(nrow(df))
  Account_from <- df$Account_from
  Account_to <- df$Account_to
  Value <- df$Value
  Timestamp <- df$Timestamp

  df$Tot_val_out[k] <- sum(Value[which(Account_from == Account_from[k] & Timestamp %in% (Timestamp[k]-(1:0)) & nr<=k)])
  df$Tot_val_in[k] <- sum(Value[which(Account_to == Account_from[k] & Timestamp %in% (Timestamp[k]-(1:0)) & nr<=k)])
  df$Transactions_previous4[k] <- length(which(Account_from == Account_from[k] & Timestamp %in% (Timestamp[k]-(3:0)) & nr<=k))
  df$Transactions_previous2[k] <- length(which(Account_from == Account_from[k] & Timestamp %in% (Timestamp[k]-(1:0)) & nr<=k))
}

dfout <- cbind(df,
               with(df,
                    data.frame(Tot_val_out_1time = ave(Value,Timestamp,FUN = sum),
                               val_out_prev_val_out = ave(Value, Account_from, FUN = function(x) c(0,x[-1]/x[-length(x)])))))
```

such that

```
> dfout
  Account_from Account_to Value Timestamp Tot_val_out Tot_val_in Transactions_previous4 Transactions_previous2 Tot_val_out_1time val_out_prev_val_out
1            1          2    10         1          10          0                      1                      1                45             0.000000
2            1          3    15         1          25          0                      2                      2                45             1.500000
3            3          4    20         1          20         15                      1                      1                45             0.000000
4            2          1    10         2          10         10                      1                      1                35             0.000000
5            1          3    25         2          50         10                      3                      3                35             1.666667
6            2          1    15         3          25          0                      2                      2                25             1.500000
7            1          3    10         3          35         25                      4                      2                25             0.400000
8            1          4    20         4          30         15                      5                      2                20             2.000000
```

Comment: Thanks, I have been running it for four hours now, but it still isn't finished. Dataset with 1 million transactions. I assume this is normal?

Comment: @florisviss since I used `for` loop, it would be rather slow when you have many rows. There might be some  simpler ways, but I have no further idea